# How to mount an ISO onto a drive without using explorer or PowerShell?

Tags: windows, boot, cmd.exe, iso-image, repair

I want to mount an ISO onto my drive, however I cannot get into the actual Operating System, it is stuck on Startup Repair.

I have managed to get the ISO onto the drive using `xcopy`, however I cannot mount it as it will not let me access PowerShell.

I have tried everything to my knowledge, but it continues to not work.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to make a working Windows installation ISO,, use the Media Creation Tool to make a bootable USB with the ISO image, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10, or with Rufus, https://rufus.onl/how-to-make-a-windows-10-bootable-usb-with-rufus/ , if it's an older Windows version.

Comment: Are you trying to boot from an ISO? What exactly are you doing?